# Transfer parts from a previous version of a file?

Tags: git, edit, development-environment

I often write a draft version of a file, commit it, and then start fresh using what I've learnt.  I often cut-and-paste the good parts from the draft version.

The problem is if I `checkout` the draft (of the file), it will overwrite the new version (of the file), because they have the same name... [this is all just one file]

Ideally, edit both draft (old) and refresh (new) versions in `vim`, something like this pretend syntax:

```
vi HEAD^^/Myfile Myfile
```

How can I transfer information between two versions of a file?

- `stash` the current version, `checkout` the older version, copy it *out of the git repository*, and reapply the stash. Now I have access to both version, but not very git-like!
- check it out with a different name, and leave it sitting in the directory (like `myfile_draft.ext`). I have access to both versions, but prone to getting committed accidentally.
- interactive patch. An awkward and unnatural way to edit files!

Is there a natural git-like way?

Or, is my use of a draft the problem, and there's a better, more git-like way to build from an initial version?

Answer (score 1):

One possible option

*Initial state:*

```
A - B - C - D (HEAD, draft-version)
```

Create a new branch and reset it to the new "starting point":

```
git checkout -b new-version
git reset A
```

*Intermediate state:*

```
A (HEAD, new-version) - B - C - D (draft-version)
```

The changes from `B`, `C` and `D` will appear as uncommitted changes on the 'new-version' branch. Now you can edit the files, keep what you like, drop what you don't like and commit again.

```
git commit
```

*Final result:*

```
A - B - C - D (draft-version)
 \
  E (HEAD, new-version)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Sorry, it took me a while to relate your suggestion to my situation. The difficulty is the code (an algorithm) is all in one file. The whole project is just one file. So, versions `B`, `C`, and `D` couldn't co-exist simultaneously in the same directory as commit `A`.

Comment: Perhaps having one file is the problem? For an algorithm, it's simpler to have all the code together. Also, this is java, and the changes are to methods in a class, so need to be in the same file. I guess I could subclass the changes in another file, and split other aspects between files (e.g. test cases, utility methods). On the one hand, this seems the tail wagging the dog, complicating the project, just so `git` can have two versions in the same directory. But on the other hand, perhaps separate files would be a simpler approach in its own right... even for experimenting with an algorithm.